# Find cepstrum of a function with dirac function

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft

$$x[n] = d[n] + a\cdot d[n − N_p]\ ,\ \ |a| < 1$$

I need the complex and real cepstrum of this function as well as what would happen for $N=N_p/6$ for the DFT approximation $$x_p[n] = \frac{1}{N}  \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\log(X[k]) e^{j2kn/N}$$.

It is a school assignment in which I am missing a lo of the functions required to proceed so  also any info you can link is greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes you are right I apologise

Comment: thanks for fixing that! I'm deleting that now obsolete comment :)